# Import Visual FoxPro DBF file to Excel 2016

Tags: excel, oledb, visual-foxpro

When i try to import the dbf file to Excel it scrambles my native characters (like č,ž,š).
I tried importing it by going to Data->From Other Sources->From Data Connection Wizard->Other/Advanced 
And selecting MS OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro,
But it's showing me this error:
"*Provider is no longer available. Ensure that the provider is installed properly*"

Naturally i tried installing the OLEDB provider and registering the oledb32.dll and oledb32r.dll but it didn't help.

**Note**: I could use some Third party program but it has to be an Excel import unfortunately, and given the nature of this data it has to have those specific characters

Comment: VFPOLEDB driver is not oledb32.dll but vfpoledb.dll. I doubt it would work but you can try downloading and installing it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839 I don't know why but whenever I try to use it from Excel, excel is crashing (but I can programmatically transfer data from VFP to excel using that driver from within VFP or C#).

Comment: The crash can be awoided if you run excel as an administrator. I dont use VFP unfortunatley, will try with your sugestion. Tnx

Comment: It doesn't make sense to run excel as admin to prevent that crash but thanks anyway (I wouldn't use excel anyway unless programmatically:) FYI running as Admin doesn't prevent the crash, I just tried. Should be something else.

Comment: So i tried your suggestion and I had no luck. I've been digging around and apparently this problem persists for years. If I find some solution will post it ;)

Comment: One question which has not been clarified is:  Is this a one-time import of the VFP data?   Or does this need to be a continuous operation?   The answer to that could likely affect the advice we might have to offer.

Comment: It would need to be a continious operation, but i decided to translate the VFP Code to .NET and placed the function in a .dll for future use. But it surley would be usefull to know where the problem is. I have a fealing that this isn't the last time I'll (or someone else) encounter this problem